# How to create type id using Custom Serilizer?

Tags: json, jackson

I'm making a DB replication mechanism. I just want to send over an object once over the network. I have implemented a custom serializer that makes a reference to the object using an UUID instead of serializing the object itself. On the other side I plan to just look up the UUID in DB in order to create the none serialized object.

The problem I have is that Jackson expects a type id from my custom serializer. How do I create a type id?

I got the follwing class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,    property="objectType")
public class Brand implements Serializable {
    private String uuid;

    @JsonSerialize(using = EntitySerializer.class)
    private Producer producer = null;

    // Omitting getters and setters
}
```

and

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="objectType")
public class Producer extends Entity implements Serializable {
    private String uuid;
    private String name;

    //Omitting getters and setters.
}
```

To serialize Producer i got the following serializer:

```
public class EntitySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Entity> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Entity value, JsonGenerator jgen,
        SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    jgen.writeString(value.getUUID());  
}
```

}

When I serialize I get the following error because I don't generate any @JsonTypeInfo type Id.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Type id handling not implemented for type com.fodolist.model.Producer (through reference chain: com.fodolist.server.callprocessor.SyncContainter["one"]->com.fodolist.model.Brand["producer"])
```

Is there any better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at `@JsonIdentityInfo`; one of id generators creates UUIDs to use as ids. By default the first instance will be serialized in its entirety (otherwise it is not possible to deserialize the data), but you can change that by using `@JsonIdentityReference` to indicate that all instances are to be serialized using just the id (generated, or accessed via property).

Answer (score 0):

In case the uuid field is already set, you can use the PropertyGenerator as follow:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator =  ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uuid")
public class Producer extends Entity {
....
}
```